# Orthogonal decomposition of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $M, N \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are positive definite matrices. How can we find matrices $A,B$ such that $A^TA=M$ and   $B^TB=N$,  but  $A^TB=B^TA=0_{n \times n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Try Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: I don't understand how to impose orthogonality

Comment: M, N are real positive definite matrices, therefore they are symmetrical. Every real symmetrical matrix is unitarily diagonalisable (sorry for my Maths English if it’s hard to understand).

Comment: Ok, got it. $A=[M^{\frac{1}{2}}~0]^T$ and $B=[0~N^{\frac{1}{2}}]^T$